# How call rest api in angularjs which returns boolean

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have a rest api which returns true/false, i called my rest api in postman and it works and it returns true or false.
I need to call this service in angularjs,
what change should i do in my angular js to make it return true/false, beacause now it returnsobjewct object.

```
function checkIsActive() {            
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/myservice/v1/testService').query().$promise;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For APIs that return boolean values, use the $http service:

```
function checkIsActive() {            
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/myservice/v1/testService');
}
```

The $resource service returns arrays for the `.query` action method and objects for the `.get` action method.

---

> when i have `console.log(myService.checkIsActive());` then it print `[object Object]` still it does not return boolean.

Keep in mind that the service returns a promise from which the data needs to be extracted:

```
var promise = myService.checkIsActive();
promise.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i changed my code to use $http.get as you mentioned above. and now when i have console.log('this is test service ' +   myService.checkIsActive());    then it print '
this is test service [object Object]'    still it does not return boolean.

Comment: The boolean needs to be extracted from the promise. See update to answer.